# Trying to get Javascript to select each child from a multiple select box

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I am trying to use PHP to get Javascript to select values in a multiple select box dependent on a particular GET.

Here's my code:

```
if (isset($_GET["parent"])  && ($_GET['parent'] !== '')) {
    $parent = $_GET['parent'];

    echo '<script type=text/javascript>
        document.getElementById("locpick").value="'.stripslashes($parent).'";
            </script>';


$reschild = mysql_query("SELECT child_id from loc_child_xref where loc_id='".$locrow['loc_id']."'");
while ($childrow = mysql_fetch_array($reschild)) {
    $childloc = mysql_query("SELECT loc_id, loc_desc from location where loc_id='".$childrow['child_id']."'");
    while ($childlocrow = mysql_fetch_array($childloc)) {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript>
            var pl = document.getElementById("child");
        for(var i=0; i<pl.options.length;i++) {
        if(pl.options[i].value == "' . stripslashes($childlocrow['loc_id']).'") {
            pl.options[i].selected = true;
            }
            }
            </script>';
            }

}  
}
```

It selects the first id, but doesn't select all the children for the second.

Comment: You would be better to just add a `selected="selected"` attribute to the `<option>`s as you generate the HTML, instead of adding loads of little random sections of Javascript to the DOM.

Comment: Fixed it. where loc_id='".$locrow['child_id']."' etc etc, should be $parent

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it. where

```
loc_id='".$locrow['child_id']."'
```

etc etc, should be

```
$parent
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm glad you fixed it, but I do agree with @DaveRandom. Your code outputs a new `<script>` for each `$childlocrow` in the result set. A cleaner solution would be to add `selected="selected"` to the relevant `<options>` using PHP. If that's not possible, though, you should consider `echo`ing the id's to a JavaScript array and perform checks on that. That way, you only need one `<script>` block.

Comment: Hrm, it is good that I know this now, and will keep it in mind for the future - I don't think we have enough development time for this now though.